# I have the Flutter plugins installed in Android Studio, but it doesn't give me the option to create a project

Tags: flutter, android-studio-4.0

Uninstall the android studio and install it again and I still don't get the option to create a project with flutter

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you've installed the plugins, make sure the plugins are **enabled**. And then close the Android Studio and open it again.

[image]

Comment: But as I enable them when I click on install it asks me to restart the android studio I do it and the result is that of the second image that I show

Comment: would you please upload the _flutter's plugin description_ images (just like what I've uploaded) @FreyblenGohiter

Comment: please enable the `Android APK Support` and `Android NDK Support` plugins and the restart the Android Studio.

Comment: I needed that, I already got the expected result thank you very much for the help